# Set current Directory in C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to change the Directory in my C# code so I can run a batch file.

For example:

`D:\Program Files\Common Files\asd.bat`

However when I use `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"D:\Program Files\Common Files\asd.bat");` it gives me two errors.

1. Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
   Error
2. 'System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(string)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

Could anyone help me please. I'm still new to C#.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error elsewhere. Can you post more of the code?

Comment: you probably mean Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"D:\Program Files\Common Files") - you're including the full file path as the directory name

Comment: The error must be somewhere else. Maybe you did put your code directly in the class and not inside a member?

Comment: Please show us the **entire** contents of the file where that error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks guys I wrote it inside a member and it worked! (Y)

Comment: @M.A I write my answer then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error must be somewhere else. Maybe you did put your code directly in the class and not inside a member?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but the accepted answer isn't correct.

Getting errors like this means the reference to a library is not correctly set up (either a using is missing or a dependency to a .NET class or NUGET package is not set). In this case, you can either declare `using System.IO;` on the top or reference the methods by fully qualifying the namespace (like I am doing it below).

Regarding the method you want to use, there is additionally another issue:

When you call `System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path)`, then it must be a path **without** filename. You passed the full path including the file name `asd.bat`.

To get the path, use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`, like:

```
var pathWithFileName = @"D:\Program Files\Common Files\asd.bat";
var pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathWithFileName);
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathOnly);
```

The `@` symbol in front of the string is required, without it the `\` would be treated as escape character, not as directory separator.

If you want to check if the path exists beforehand, use

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathOnly))
   System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathOnly);
```

---

<sup>**Note:** Of course, you can abbreviate the code above by declaring `using System.IO;` on the top - I didn't do it here, because I wanted to show where the method comes from.</sup>